# finding out gracefully the version of makeindex

Tags: java, file, latex

I wrote something like a make-tool for latex documentation (in fact a maven plugin https://github.com/Reissner/maven-latex-plugin).

As this invokes just a bunch of command line tools
and i frequently have problems when new versions of those tools come up, i decided to provide a way to check the versions (in fact a goal).
E.g. i let my tool invoke `pdflatex -v` to get version of pdflatex.
This works fine for all tools but `makeindex`,
because `makeindex` offers no regular way, to get the version and nothing but that.

To find out by hand i just type `makeindex` and then ctrl-d on my bash shell.
The result is then

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2020] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file stdin...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in stdout.
Transcript written in stderr.
```

The keystroke ctrl-d seems to be tied to unicode 0004.
So from the bash shell, this works just fine.

Is there a way to do that with a java execution?
I tried to invoke (java string)
`"makeindex \u0004"` and related.
No success,... makeindex just quits with an error.
To be honest, I dont know why because from the terminal all is fine.

The last problem to solve: the procedure shall be platform independent.

Now tried some hack providing a dummy file.
But of course this is the contrary of elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use texlive, you could use

```
tlmgr info --only-installed --data="localrev" makeindex
```

which returns something like

```
 52851
```

This is the revision information from the makeindex package you have installed. This is not the version number, but should be enough to detect if the installed version changes.

Comment: shure that you mean tlmgr?? I dont have that in my texlife.. Hm, do I need some exotic package?? Seems to be quite crucial... I am confused.

Comment: @user2609605 `tlmgr` is the basic tool for installing or updating packages. It should be installed by default.

Comment: i have rpm based distro. Did some research and I know i dont have that package manager... Sorry. So solution is not so much generic, im afraid. Also, I cannot define range conditions on the versions like that. Maybe still a solution. But i will wait further suggestions.